# speed up HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Hi all since i am new here i hope this is the right place.
i am trying out HttpWebRequest to check out the status code (in this case response) from different websites.
On ok the response is very fast and no form freeze.
On a connect failure the form freezes and take's around 5 seconds
bypassing the freezing can be done with a background worker.
But is there a way to say, there is no response in 1 second, forget this one and go to the next.

```
 try
        {

            string url;
            url = (LoopUrlFromListboxOrStream ) ; //example

            // Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                label1.Text = (myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
            // Releases the resources of the response.
            myHttpWebResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            label2.Text = (ex.Status.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label2.Text = (ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: If you're only interested in the status code, the response time can be further improved by setting the [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.method) to "HEAD", to avoid downloading the entire content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [HttpWebRequest.Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netcore-3.1) property to a low enough value that suits your needs.

In you case

```
myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 1;
```

Before doing GetResponse()

Comment: Except its milliseconds , it works like a charm . Than you.

Comment: @Snoopy well, never said it was not milliseconds :P, just multiply it by 1000 if you like to manage the value as seconds.
Can you mark it as an answer please?